# Haskell: Parsing Positive Integers

Tags: haskell, parsec

I am trying to parse positive integers in Haskell and I wrote this:

```
number ::  [Char] st Data.Functor.Identity.Identity [Char]
number =   do
           many1 digit
```

But I am getting this error:

```
 • Expecting three fewer arguments to ‘[Char]’
   Expected kind ‘k0 -> (* -> *) -> * -> *’, but ‘[Char]’ has kind ‘*’
 • In the type signature:
    number :: [Char] st Identity [Char]
    Failed, modules loaded: none.'
```

Why is this error thrown and how can I fix it?

Comment: So you want to *parse* positive integers?

Comment: Yes I want to parse positive integers.

Comment: But your type `[Char] st...` does not make much sense?

Answer (score 4):

Well it is simply the type that is wrong here.

If you write `:t many1 digit` in the terminal, you get:

```
Prelude Text.Parsec.Combinator Text.Parsec.Char Text.Parsec.Prim> :t many1 digit
many1 digit :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s u m [Char]
```

So you can write the type signature of your function as:

```
number :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s u m [Char]
number =  many1 digit
```

(or simply omit a type signature).

I don't see why you want a less generic type signature because potentially in the future you want to use `number` for something else.

The reason why the compiler gives this error, is because the type `[Char]` has "no type parameters" you can fill in. So the compiler get confused why to call `[Char]` with `st`, and so on.